# how stream methods working internally in Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am having below code and trying to collect the employees with distinct by name.

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Employee employee = new Employee("test", "123");
        final Employee employee1 = new Employee("demo", "3232");
        final Employee employee2 = new Employee("test", "323");
        final Employee employee3 = new Employee("hello", "123");

        final List<Employee> employees = List.of(employee, employee1, employee2, employee3);

         final List<Employee> collect = employees.stream()
            .filter(it -> {
                System.out.println("filter" + it.getName());
                return distinctByKey().test(it);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());


        System.out.println(collect);
        System.out.println(seen);

    }

  private static Predicate<Employee> distinctByKey() {
        final Set<String> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        System.out.println("set"+seen);
        return employee -> {
            System.out.println("keyExtractor" + employee.getName());
            return seen.add(employee.getName());
        };
    }
```

Employee class is having name and address fields.

If I am used filter like above it's creating new `Set` every time in `distinctByKey` method and printing like below:

```
filtertest
set[]
keyExtractortest
filterdemo
set[]
keyExtractordemo
filtertest
set[]
keyExtractortest
filterhello
set[]
keyExtractorhello
[Employee{name='test', address='123'}, Employee{name='demo', address='3232'}, Employee{name='test', address='323'}, Employee{name='hello', address='123'}]
```

Here distinct not working as expected because Set created for each elements.

If I change the filter like below

```
final List<Employee> collect = employees.stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Only one time `Set` was created and distinct also working correctly.

What is the difference between these two approach? How first approach is creating Set each time but second approach creating Set only once?

Comment: In the first example, you call `distinctByKey()` once per item (inside the `filter` lambda). In the second example, you call `distinctByKey()` once, and pass the result into `filter`.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is essentially, what is the difference between:

```
.filter(it -> {
    System.out.println("filter" + it.getName());
    return distinctByKey().test(it);
})
```

and

```
.filter(distinctByKey())
```

What `filter` does internally is it is passed a Predicate, and it calls that predicate once for each item in the stream. In your first example, the predicate is a function that calls `distinctByKey()` and then tests the input against the predicate returned by that function. In the second example, you are calling `distinctByKey()` once and passing that predicate directly to the `filter` method.

The key difference here is that in the first example `distinctByKey()` is called once per element, and internally creates a new Set for each element, while in the second example `distinctByKey()` is called only once and the Set functions as shared state for the filtering function.

This confusion is partially caused by the fact that your `distinctByKey()` method returns a stateful predicate, and this is one of the reasons that such stateful predicates [are discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).

Comment: Also, java streams are not 'typed' in regards to the 'parallel or sequential' dimension, and this `distinctByKey` will break in very nasty ways (race conditions, bugs that may or may not show depending on a million random factors - due to not establishing HA/HB and accessing shared state) if ever used in a parallel stream. Stateless predicates trivially avoid this issue.

Comment: In fairness I think since this `distinctByKey()` uses a concurrent hash set, it should work correctly in a parallel stream.

Comment: Somehow my eyes saw `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet` and brain interpreted `new HashSet`, not sure what happened there.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, the `Predicate` of the filter is represented by a lambda expression, which internally uses another `Predicate`. Basically, you're confusing these two predicates.

The argument of the filter always evaluated **only once**

But during the execution of the `Predicate` in the first snippet (*meaning method* `Predicate.test()` *which fires the logic represented by the lambda*), a **new** nested `Predicate` returned by `distinctByKey()` would be created for every element in the stream which reaches the `filter`:

```
.filter(it -> {
     System.out.println("filter" + it.getName());
     return distinctByKey().test(it);
})
```

In the second snippet, `filter` is using `Predice` returned by `distinctByKey()` directly. The call `distinctByKey()` would be executed only once and all the element would be evaluated against the same stateful `Predicate`, capturing a `Set` (as the result all the previously encountered unique elements would be reflected in the set).

```
.filter(distinctByKey())
```